# Mongoose unique restricted by ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Users` collection and an `Events` collection. The users collection is unremarkable, here's my events Schema:

```
schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
            type        :  mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref         :  'User',
            required    :  true
          },
    name: {
             type       :  String,
             unique     :  true,
             required   :  true
          }
});
```

This works. I cannot create an event without a username and the `name` property is required and unique. Problem is, it's unique on the database. So if user A creates an event called "Meet up", no other user can create an event with that name. I want the "uniqueness" to be restricted by user, so User A cannot create two events named "Meet up", but user B can create one with that name.

How would I approach this?

Comment: I'm thinking you'll need some kind of.. compound index that is unique. Here's the dox for 2.7 from a quick search: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/indexes.html 4.0 doesn't include such an example, but i think it's the same.

Comment: @KevinB I'll check upon that. I'm unsure what compound indexes are or how to implement them, so it might take a while whilst I dive in. Will let you know how it goes. Thank you!